# Generate labels and checkboxes in Visual Studio for each row in a db query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, checkbox

I want to have a label and checkbox for each row in from my query.

I needed to get the number of records from my sql query, but I read that SELECT statements will not work with `int numberOfRecords = sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();`. So **what should I do instead to get the number of records selected from my query (see code below)?**

**Is this code enough to do what I need to generate labels and checkboxes from a db? Or am I missing something?**

Side Note: I do not want to use the Repeater Control. I have tried it, and it isn't robust enough as I program more complicated pages.

ASP

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
    <asp:Label ID="LabelFormFields" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxListFormFields" runat="server">
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

C#

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Events2"].ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlConn2.Open();

            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand())
            {
                sqlCmd2.Connection = sqlConn2;
                sqlCmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                sqlCmd2.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT DisplayName FROM FormField WHERE EventId = 1 AND Visible = 0 ORDER BY ColumnOrder ASC;");
                sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                int numberOfRecords = //something here;
                using (SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd2.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sqlReader.Read())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRecords; i++)
                        {
                            var PanelFormFields = new Panel();
                            var LabelFormFields = new Label();
                            var ListItemFormFields = new ListItem();


                            LabelFormFields.Text = sqlReader["DisplayName"].ToString();
                            CheckBoxListFormFields.Items.Add(new ListItem(sqlReader["DisplayName"].ToString(), "C"));
                            PanelFormFields.Controls.Add(LabelFormFields);
                            PanelFormFields.Controls.Add(CheckBoxListFormFields);
                        }
                    }
                }

                sqlConn2.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about the [`ListView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) control? It's quite robust on it's own.

Comment: `Repeater control isn't robust enough` and your current code is? I don't agree repeater control is ideal for your requirement. Also, `while (sqlReader.Read())` will run for each row so there is no need of a for loop again.

Comment: @EBrown: I can check the ListView Control, but I would prefer to code on my own if possible.

Comment: @Rahul: After I do this, I need to get what is and isn't checked from the checkboxes. After struggling with the Repeater for days, I cannot get access to the checkboxes and the data. I feel like coding it from scratch will make it easier for me to see what is going on and customize it as I develop more of this program.

Comment: @WebDev - Just refer to some basic repater control tutorial. It's damn easy when compared to what you are currently doing.

Comment: I have, and the Repeater works for what I am doing above. However for step 2 of my program, I need a way to access what is and isn't checked. We cannot reference CheckBoxList1 nor Repeater1.CheckBoxList1 when a CheckBoxList is in a Repeater.

Answer (score 1):

int numberOfRecords = sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery(); //you will get the record numbers; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx
But you don't need the numbers here.
your **while (sqlReader.Read())** will help to to control the bounds of loop. Based on your description, you don't need this reader. just fill a datatable, then assign it to a datagrid control. as per you want to display a checkbox for each line, you need to make a custom column. 
Here is a good sample about how to implement a checkbox and a label in datagrid: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7629/Using-CheckBoxes-within-the-DataGrid-control-to-se

Answer (score 1):

use DataTable.Load(IDataReader reader) method to fill a DataTable and then use DataTable.Rows.Count to get number of Records. change your code to something like this:

```
.
.
sqlCmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
sqlCmd2.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT DisplayName FROM FormField WHERE EventId = 1 AND Visible = 0 ORDER BY ColumnOrder ASC;");

int numberOfRecords;

using (System.Data.DataTable dataTable =new System.Data.DataTable())
{                    
     dataTable.Load(sqlCmd2.ExecuteReader());
     numberOfRecords = dataTable.Rows.Count;  

     for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
          System.Data.DataRow dr = dataTable.Rows[i];
          var PanelFormFields = new Panel();
          var LabelFormFields = new Label();
          var ListItemFormFields = new ListItem();

          LabelFormFields.Text = dr["DisplayName"].ToString();
          CheckBoxListFormFields.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["DisplayName"].ToString(), "C"));
          PanelFormFields.Controls.Add(LabelFormFields);
          PanelFormFields.Controls.Add(CheckBoxListFormFields);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one answer. Please note that I put the code in the `Page_Init` rather than `Page_Load` because the `Page_Load` reloads with every postback and any changes that were not yet written to the database could go away.

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = GetData();
        //int numberOfRecords = dt.Rows.Count;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            var PanelFormFields = new Panel();
            var LabelFormFields = new Label();
            var ListItemFormFields = new ListItem();

            LabelFormFields.Text = row[0].ToString();
            CheckBoxListFormFields.Items.Add(new ListItem(row[0].ToString(), "C"));
            PanelFormFields.Controls.Add(LabelFormFields);
            PanelFormFields.Controls.Add(CheckBoxListFormFields);
        }
    }

    private DataTable GetData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Events2"].ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlConn2.Open();
            string sql = string.Format("SELECT DisplayName FROM FormField WHERE EventId = 1 AND Visible = 0 ORDER BY ColumnOrder ASC;");

            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConn2))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd2))
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Also note that I refactored to use a `GetData()` method to retrieve the `DataTable` object and simplify the `Page_Init` method.  I did not close the `sqlConn2` object because the `using` block does this for me. I also used a `DataAdapter` because it is a simple, fast way to fill a table. Finally, while I kept the `numberOfRecords` in a commented line to show you how you can get the count, if you need it, it is commented because the `foreach` loop doesn't need this value.